# How to display chat date and time for every message in webchat developed in bot framework SDKV4 using C#?

Tags: c#, html, css, botframework

I have developed a chatBot using bot framework SDKV4 in C# and the channel is WebChannel. All is working well but what i wanted to achieve is:

Along with each message user types in or Bot replies i want a time stamp to be printed along with it For example if we take a simple echo bot what it does is replies back what user had typed. If we assusme below is the message and reply in echo bot:

User: Hi

a minute ago

Bot: You Typed Hi

2 minutes ago

If we see without any changes the as is BOt will have the time stamp as something like JustNow under each message in Webchannel.

What i want to acheive is tol display the actual time stamp:

User: Hi

10:00 AM

Bot: You typed : Hi

10:01 AM

If only time is not possible it will be the whole long date or with date that is also fine but i am unable to know how to achieve this?

Did some googling but did not get anything concrete. Though i found below GIt Hub link provided went to a 404 page error

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/preview/samples/timestamp-grouping/index.html

This was part of issue post:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/985

Since my bot is a Web channel in my index.html page i tried to put below option as one of the style options:
 groupTimestamp: true

But did not do much of help.

To make my issue/query more clear:
When i inspect the Bot page i get the below thing:

[image: Sample screenshot of inspect]

Currently it displlays 25 mins ago, what i want to display is the time stamp that is just above the one which is highlighted in the inspect image given above.

Can any please let me know how to achieve the above ask?

Thanks in Advance

Regards

ChaitanyaNG

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample you are wanting, [05.custom-components/g.activity-status](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/05.custom-components/g.activity-status/README.md). This demonstrates how you can alter the activity status, including the time stamp. It’s relatively easy to setup though, depending what elements you are introducing /altering, you may need to adjust some of the CSS.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for the time and quick reply. Just have a doubt, I am using currently the webchat-es5.js as the web channel bot should bee opened in IE also. Will the details has react will it work int his case also? If it works can you please me to transform the given HTML code to the es5 format. I am not sure on actually how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Webchat StyleOptions, add the below attribute.

```
timestampFormat: 'absolute',
```

**Explanation**

'absolute' will render exact time like "August 3, 10:30 AM"

'relative' will render as "1 minute ago"

===========================================================

```
var styleOptions = {
        bubbleBackground: 'rgba(196, 196, 205, .3)',
        bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(255, 230, 0, .3)',
        botAvatarImage: ChatImagePath + 'icon_round.png',
        botAvatarInitials: 'CB',
        userAvatarImage: ChatImagePath + 'user_icon.png',
        userAvatarInitials: 'YOU',
        hideUploadButton: true,
        timestampFormat: 'absolute', // 'relative'
        sendBoxButtonColorOnFocus: '#999999',
        sendBoxButtonColorOnHover: '#004E9A',
        sendBoxButtonColor: '#999999'
    };
   window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
        directLine: directLine,
        locale: 'en-US',
        // Passing 'styleOptions' when rendering Web Chat
        styleOptions
    },
    document.getElementById('chatbotdiv')
   );
```